# Linguistic relationship between Hebrew and Greek

Tags: comparative-linguistics, semitic-languages

In the modern linguistic school of thought, are Ancient Hebrew and Ancient Greek related? Hebrew is classified as [Afroasiatic->Semitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroasiatic_languages), while Greek is [Indo-European->Hellenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages). However, in Jewish tradition, they are considered related.

A *Sefer Torah* (special scroll with the 5 Books of Moses) is allowed to be written in Greek, due to being able to translate it perfectly. (See answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18819/translation-to-greek); see [my question here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48542/was-a-sefer-torah-ever-actually-written-in-greek) about if it was ever done.) However, this Greek that was mentioned is an extinct language ([per Maimonides](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Tefillin,_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.1.19), mentioned in the question).

The Talmud occasionally makes references to Greek words in interpreting Biblical verses as well. I don't have specific examples right now, but i know they exist.

Is this view shared by modern linguists?

Related: [Is Classical Hebrew an Indo-European language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/is-classical-hebrew-an-indo-european-language) and [Can Modern Hebrew be considered an Indo-European language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/89/can-modern-hebrew-be-considered-an-indo-european-language)

Comment: One verse with a few Greek words is [Daniel 3:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%203%3A5&version=NIV;WLC) for the instruments, e.g. the kithara. Interestingly, at least one [commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/barnes/daniel/3.htm) cites the argument that this suggests the inauthenticity of Daniel, though I don't think that's commonly believed now.

Comment: But *kithara* is considered a pre-Greek word (i.e., A loan word in proto-Greek from an unknown other language).

Comment: @jknappen I don't know the history much myself - I just know that verse is often written about as having Greek instruments with names that look like transliterations and don't appear elsewhere in the Bible. Perhaps the commentaries are wrong, though. Actually, Barnes goes on to agree with your point: "That such names are found given to instruments of music by the Greeks is certain; but it is not certain from where they obtained the name."

Comment: Can we protect this question? The amount of low quality answers is astounding.

Answer (score 16):

You are using *related* in two different senses.

When linguists refer to languages being related, they almost always mean "genetically related" - stemming ultimately from the same linguistic source. Most linguists today do not regard Hebrew and Greek as genetically related, but there is a respectable minority who believe that we can trace relationship further back than Afro-Asiatic and Indo-European to a superphylum, such as Nostratic, or Eurasiatic, depending on the particular theory. In those linguists' conception, Hebrew and Greek are related, but very distantly, in the way that a horse and a fly are very distantly related.

Whatever kind of relationship the Jewish tradition talks about it is nothing like the linguistic conception of genetic relationship. It sounds from your account that it is something to do with suitability for use in particular contexts. Such a concept is purely  a product of thinking about languages and not about their innate or historical properties, whereas the idea genetic relationship is predicated on there being an objective historical relationship, that of common descent.

Comment: My guess is that the notion of suitability in question could also have to do with the status of Greek as a highly developed literary language and in particular with the availability of translations for all relevant Hebrew words -- or at least an established process for coining new Hebrew-based words in Greek. (But this is just a semi-educated guess based on superficial knowledge.)

Comment: This framing of common descent (i.e. the same parents, not just some shared ancestors) leads to various problems, first of all the assumption of a (necessarily small) unique Proto Indo European homeland, which stands in contrast with many if not most existing languages that are an amalgamation of various language dialects. Why is English noted as a Germanic language, but does use *do* inflationary, a manner it took on from Celtic!?

Comment: @vectory: because _do_-support is notable specifically because borrowings from Celtic into English (especially grammatical borrowings) are so rare.

Comment: @vectory or people who claim that English is a Scandinavian/North Germanic language because it uses a word order that is closer to modern Danish than modern German. In reality this is because Old English came under heavy linguistic influence from Old Norse due to Viking colonization in the British Isles.

Answer (score -1):

> The Indo-Semitic hypothesis maintains that a genetic relationship
>   exists between Indo-European and Semitic and that the
>   Indo-European and the Semitic language families descend from a
>   prehistoric language ancestral to them both. The theory has never been widely accepted by contemporary linguists in modern times, but historically it has had a number of supporting advocates and arguments, particularly in the 19th and 20th centuries.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Semitic_languages)

Comment: People can hypothesize anything, though; is there any real evidence for this one? I don't know any current linguists who actually believe in "Nostratic".

Comment: @Draconis There are at least a few https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostratic_languages#21st_century https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_R._Bomhard

Comment: Welcome to the site, Sorb! Please edit your answer with some content, posting a link and adding a quote from the link is not really a useful answer.

Answer (score -6):

I don't know maybe in the letters. Alef= Alph(a) (ph and f make same the sound)    bet= bet(a)  Gimmel= Gamm(a) Dalef= Delt(a) Heh= Epsilon ? Vav= Upsilon? Zayin= Zeta ? Chet= Et(A) Tet= Thet(a) yod= iot(a) (d to t to d iod(a)) Yoda :). Kaf= Kapp(a) ( f and ph f and p make the same sounds) Lamed= Lambd(a) Mem= Mu Nun= Nu Samech =Xi? Ayin= Omicron? Peh= Pi or Phi Rho= Resh (no sh sound in Greek also so Reh) Sigma= Shin Tau= Tav Psi= Tsadeh? Chi and Omega?

So also transliteration. If you notice this letter are identical I put the (a) so to show how to Bet and just add an "a" Beta. I put questions because some are not as similar, but shin is transliterated sigma in Greek. Well, maybe the alphabet or alef-bet see it is similar. So I know of people who teach Biblical Hebrew and Greek, well on Facebook one Izzy Avraham and one of his lessons showed how Greek was familiar with Hebrew in letters. Then How even the Latin alphabet was familiar with Hebrew. I mean you can see it on Youtube.

Then another thing notice how in Hebrew Chet is also Het but in Frankish the name Childeric so it is really Hildr then how Charles is Karl it seems to be similar to Chet. Then how I and J in Old Norse are pronounced like y like Jorvic is Yorvic or York. Sorry of the topic I don't know but anyone can see there are similarities in the names of these letters.

Comment: They both use alphabets originating in the Phoenician alphabet. That does not tell us much about the languages themselves. Our Latin script then originates from the same via the Greek alphabet.

Comment: As Vladimir F says, both the Greek and the Hebrew writing systems are descended from the Phoenician abjad (a sort of consonant-only alphabet). That's why the letter names are similar. Unfortunately, this doesn't tell us anything about the relationship of the languages themselves; Swahili, Nahuatl, and English are all written in the same alphabet, for example, but there's no genetic relationship between those languages (at least as far back as current methods can reconstruct).

Answer (score -8):

Allow me. Greek is actually called Hellenic and the name of the country is call Hellas or actually hEllas (h substituted an ancient toning system of middle ages). Ελλάς is made of El and las ie the land/nation of El. Sounds too Hebrew?

Hebrew is found in Bible yet it also has its Greek word HObreos that became Hebreoos. Again the H is a tone. Obrios Οβριος was actually means “the above waters sent by Zeus” as Dias the ....God of gods in mythology was the god that gave the flood and the living rain. Sounds too Greek?

Equally main Greek words like truth , αλήθεια al-ethos combines the divine Semitic  Lamda aleph and Greek ethos which means both «the appearance or the character “ So for Hellenic alethia/truth means the appearance of the divinity or the ethics of El. Even sacred words and mysteries (ELefsinean) use L even the Sun in Greek is Helios ie El-ios where again Semitic L comes as the light.

Bottom line is Greek and Hebrew have too many things in common that modern nationalist linguistics do not want to either admit or mention as if we are two different people. We are not. We are more connected that one can today imagine.

Comment: Do you have any credible source to support what you are saying? This is not something that is being tought in universities.

Comment: I don't know why you say `/h/` was a tone. It was a consonant like any other, which is clear from prefix mutation and Grassmann's Law. *Hellēn* comes from a pre-Greek source but you'd need more evidence than two letters to claim it was from Hebrew, especially since those two letters come right in the middle. And you're mixing up your Greek letters: *alētheia* has an eta, as in *lēthē*, while *ethos* has an epsilon.

Comment: Similarly, you're claiming _Hellēn_ with an epsilon, _alētheia_ with an alpha, and _hēlios_ with an eta all come from Semitic *el*. In other words, you seem to be claiming that having _literally any vowel followed by lambda_ is evidence of a relationship with Hebrew. Would you say English "alone", "olive", "bell", "tile" prove that English is related to Hebrew?

Comment: @Draconis, can lengthening of epsilon to eta, or vice versa, not be explained with metrics, stress, prosody and the like? With further reconstruction, most vowels are represented as PIE \*e anyhow, later vowels rather reflecting the ominous laryngeals, also semivowels, and I don't know what other processes.

Comment: @ΑθανάσιοςΚαπράλος it would be much more agreeable to assume that it's just well difficult. Roots like *el-* are just too short and too frequent for a simple analysis. I could as well propose that it relates to *ile* (island) given the many islands of Greece, especially crete. And I have at least two other derivations in the back of my mind. I wouldn't count on folk names deriving from a single source, because they are prone for glorifying folk etymology. That makes it extraordinarily *opaque*. Assume phonetic consonant lengthening for /l/ and you are left with *he* or just *e*.

Comment: @vectory Sure, but there'd have to be some pattern to it: in Attic, for example, epsilon regularly lengthens to epsilon-iota, not to eta. (Look at the epsilon-contract verbs for some attestations.) Claiming this word is an exception to that rule is an extra assumption that the straightforward derivation from _a-lēth-eia_ doesn't require, so Occam's Razor suggests the latter.

Comment: @Draconis maybe a pattern is needed to make a case, but mutation can happen spontaniously, under various circumstances. Phonetics depend on environment and not all words appear in the same environment. Endonyms are a special case, and eventually so unimportant that some folks don't even have one or use a pars pro toto. The environment is often authoritative, and the name is symbolic, which makes it prone for abstraction, so a mutation can stick.

Comment: @vectory Sorry, but that sounds like grasping at straws. At that point you're saying that a word with a clear derivation *a-lēth-eia* (with three well-attested Greek roots going back to PIE, and a very common derivation pattern) actually comes from *el-eth-eia* > *al-ēth-eia*, with the first two vowels both changing in different and unattested ways, and the first root actually coming from Hebrew, through a contact that somehow left no archaeological evidence.

Comment: @Draconis Given the assumption of a Hebrew source, relying on Hellenic Alphabet derivations is of course rather disengineous. In fact, the derivation of the alphabet does require investigation of Hebrew influence, religious or not. Just sayin': Modern Hebrew denotes L with a specific letter, but its ancient sound quality is less than certain, and the Arabic aleph at least can stand for /l/ and /i/ (and whatnot). A tripple aleph would be liable for elision--just sayin.

Comment: @Draconis now you made a different, stronger argument than before, that I was not interested in, I can likely look it up myself.. You talking about "no archaeological evidence" that's throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90164/discussion-between-draconis-and-vectory).